# Is it possilbe to automate this process?

Tags: javascript, python, vb6

I wanted to create a script to automate a work process and wonder if it's possible.

I have a system that tells me fraud investigations that previously happened, all I have to do is update the status.

The system shows me a case, i then have to find the outcome of this case in a separate excel document ( i search by a unique number assigned to each customer), it will be highlighted in here as whether it is confirmed fraud or genuine. I then have to update it as genuine or confirmed fraud depending on the information on the excel sheet.

Is there any way to automate this, and what would be the best programming language to automate this process?

Sorry if this is a nooby question.

Comment: this is very possible, you can use any programming language you want.

You need to find a way to get the case into the program, then have the program read the excel file (e.g. with a csv reader) and work on that to find the result.

How to do this exactly depends on your system/more things which you haven't mentioned. It would be best for you to try something and then post here if that doesn't work (post code attempts)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MS Excel, the best place to initiate your automation is in VBA.
VBA is built into most Microsoft Office applications, including Excel.

You can read this article as starting point:
https://trumpexcel.com/visual-basic-editor/

As Matthias said, try write some code and then post your questions here.